# Как отсортировать массив из структур?

Tags: golang, сортировка

Есть структура вида:

```golang
type RegionStruct struct {
     Id int
     Name string
     Num string
}
```

Есть массив состоящий из структуры:

```golang
var Regions []RegionStruct
```

Как отсортировать массив в алфавитном порядке по ключу `Name`? Как отсорировать массив по ключу `Num`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте
[`sort.Slice`](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Slice):

```golang
var rs = []Region{{
    Name: "C",
}, {
    Name: "A",
}, {
    Name: "B",
}}

sort.Slice(rs, func(i, j int) (less bool) {
    return rs[i].Name < rs[j].Name
})

fmt.Printf("%+v\n", rs)
// Output:
//   [{ID:0 Name:A Num:} {ID:0 Name:B Num:} {ID:0 Name:C Num:}]
```

*Playground*:
https://play.golang.org/p/TDhM3B3di_D.

Либо имплементируйте
[`sort.Interface`](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Interface).

---

<sup>Уважайте сообщество!
[Форматируйте](https://blog.golang.org/go-fmt-your-code)
ваш код и следуйте
[правилам именования](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#initialisms)!</sup>